# Is it possible for IMSI-Catchers to block emergency calls?

Tags: network, mobile

[The Wikipedia article about emergency numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emergency_telephone_number) mentions that `Most GSM mobile phones can dial emergency numbers even when the phone keyboard is locked, the phone is without a SIM card, emergency number is entered instead of the PIN or there is not a network signal (busy network).`

Is there anything that makes a regular call different from an emergency call?

Is is possible for an IMSI-catcher/cell-site simulator to block emergency calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there anything that makes a regular call different from an emergency call?

Not physically, the signal works pretty much the same way as any other call. Phone manufacturers just add the ability to dial emergency numbers with locked phone (my Samsung allows me to add my own emergency numbers, eg. parents, so they can also be called from locked phone). Operators allow emergency calls without SIM (read without payment).

> Is is possible for an IMSI-catcher/cell-site simulator to block emergency calls?

An active simulator can block them. Some were even accused of doing so by accident. It works very similarly to a jamming device. Passive devices will not prevent any types of calls.